# How to Capture Soap Web Service Output In VB.Net Console App

Tags: vb.net, soap, service, web

I have a web service project containing 3 web services (which require no input parameters) but which I need to schedule to be called once every night.  To achieve this I have done some Googling and created a console application to call the web services, which I should now be able to schedule with Windows Task Scheduler.
I am a total novice at writing console apps and have only a tiny bit of experience with VB.NET, but I achieved what I needed in the console app by entering a web reference to the web service, then applying the following simple code:

```
Sub Main()

Dim wscall As New EmployeeEmailWS

wscall.UpdateAbsenceTables()
wscall.GetThreePeriodsInAYear()
wscall.GetSixDaysInAYear()

End Sub
```

This simply triggers the three web services to run successfully.

However, having got this far, I would really like also to somehow read in the Soap web service response so that I can write it into a database as a log of each result.

The response message is as simple as the following (from SoapUI), but I just don't know how to obtain it:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<UpdateAbsenceTablesResponse xmlns="http://www.ernspnamespace7.co.uk/EmployeeWS">
<UpdateAbsenceTablesResult>
<ResponseCode>00001</ResponseCode>
<ResponseDescription>Absence Tables Successfully Updated</ResponseDescription>
</UpdateAbsenceTablesResult>
</UpdateAbsenceTablesResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction for how to obtain this response into my console app.  Particularly if I could somehow get the values of ResponseCode & ResponseDescription and convert them into Strings then I would be back in familiar territory for my basic knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Additional info.  Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.
It suddenly occurred to me that I could just add some code to the end of the web services to write their output to a database table every time they are called.  That avoided the need to bother with the XML altogether.